# How can I add a method to a FactoryBot factory?

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

Say I have a class called storage values that holds an array of values:

```
class Storage
  attr_accessor :values 

  def initialize(*vals)
    @values = vals
  end 
end
```

And a Factory set up for this class

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :storage do
    values { [1, 2, 3] }
  end
end
```

How can I add a convenience method for editing the values?

I want to have the ability to call a method called #use_values on a preexisting factory to update it, like so:

```
factory = FactoryBot.build(:storage)
factory.values #=> [1, 2, 3]

factory.use_values(4, 5, 6)
factory.values #=> [4, 5, 6]
```

I would expect the syntax to look something like this (all though this doesn't work):

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :storage do
    values { [1, 2, 3] }

    def use_values(*vals)
      self.values = vals
    end
  end
end
```

How can I do this?

I assume this should be pretty easy to do, but I can't seem to find any good resources on it.

**Note**

I'm aware that I can use options in the initial build to specify the #values return value like so:

```
FactoryBot.build(:storage, values: [4, 5, 6])
```

This is not what I want. I want a way to call a method on an already existing factory to update it, not build a factory with specific values.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to not just add the method to your `Storage` class?

Comment: You could always try FixtureReplacement (the package factory bot is based off of) - https://github.com/smtlaissezfaire/fixturereplacement :)